# Client validation does not work in Yii2 when form rendered using ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

Form rendered using ajax:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'que',
        'enableClientValidation' => true
    ]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'fk_subject')
                    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($subjects, 'id_subject', 'name'), [
                        'class'     => 'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched',
                        'ng-model'  => 'que.fk_subject',
                        'prompt'    => 'Select subject',
                        'ng-change' => 'fillTopic(que);'
                    ]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'fk_topic')
                    ->dropDownList([], [
                        'class'     => 'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched',
                        'ng-model'  => 'que.fk_topic',
                        'prompt'    => 'Select topic',
                        'ng-change' => 'openAddTopic(que);',
                        'ng-options' => 'topic.id_subject as topic.name for topic in topics',
                    ]); ?>
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'type')
                    ->dropDownList($questionTypes, [
                        'class'     => 'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched',
                        'prompt'    => 'Select question type',
                        'ng-model'  => 'que.type',
                        'ng-change' => 'addAnswerOptions(que);',
                    ]); ?>
                    <?php echo Html::submitButton('Save',
                        ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                            'name' => 'Save']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I loaded the above form using ajax in yii2 and problem is client side validation is not working with it. If I load the form content on window load it works fine.

Comment: Has probably something to do with AngularJS, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I find the solution, I will have to use `renderAjax` to get the form html or will have to add `beginpage` and `beginend` function if I use `renderPartial`

```
<?php $this->beginPage(); ?>
<?php $this->beginBody(); ?>
// Form and content redenered using ajax
<?php $this->endBody(); ?>
<?php $this->endPage(); ?>
```

so that `yii` can add client validation script with the rendered content

Answer (score 1):

make sure you use [`renderAjax()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#renderAjax()-detail) method in your controller to load this form via ajax, this way It's needed scripts will register when it loads.

other than that you need to assign a unique ID to your form to prevent possible conflicts when this form is loaded in other views.